# Converting raw bytes to image

Tags: python, image

I have a file that contains a 240x320 image but its byte format I opened it in a hex editor and got what something like an array 16 columns 4800 raw.

Im completely new to this thats why im facing trouble I have tried using a python script but it gave an error on line 17, in  data = columnvector[0][i]:

> IndexError: list index out of range.

I have tried a java code but that was an error as well, I wanted to try some c# codes but none of the codes i found explains how i can feed my file to the code. This is the python code

```
import csv
import sys
import binascii
csv.field_size_limit(500 * 1024 * 1024)

columnvector = []
with open('T1.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in csvreader:
        columnvector.append(row)
headers =['42','4D','36','84','03','00','00','00','00','00','36','00','00','00','28','00','00','00',
'40','01','00','00','F0','00','00','00','01','00','18','00','00','00','00','00','00','84','03','00','C5','00',
'00','00','C5','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00']

hexArray=[]
for i in range(0,76800):
    data = columnvector[0][i]
    hexArray.extend([data,data,data])

with open('T1.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(binascii.unhexlify(''.join(headers)))
    f.write(binascii.unhexlify(''.join(hexArray)))
```

I want to convert the file to an image using any method I honestly don't care what method to use just as long as it gets the job done.

this is some the files 
https://github.com/Mu-A/OV7670-files/tree/Help

Comment: Please share the file!

Comment: yeah sorry about that i added it now

Comment: Sorry to say, but none of those files look remotely like sensible images... they have the correct size for a greyscale 320x240 image with 8 bits per pixel but there is no semblance of any recognisable shapes or objects when you make them into JPEGs or PNGs.

Comment: Image T5 appears to have something much brighter than all the others...

Comment: https://hkalasua.wordpress.com/2017/09/11/ov7670-arduino-sd/ this is the guide im following but the difference his script needs a file with 76800 columns i couldnt find any hex editor that does that

Answer (score 1):

You can make the binary data into images without writing any Python, just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal. It is included in most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

If your image is 320x240 it should be:

- 320 * 240 bytes long if single channel (greyscale), or
- 320 * 240 * 3 if 3-channel RGB.

As your images are 76800, I am assuming they are greyscale.

So, in Terminal, to make that raw data into a JPEG, use:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 320x240 gray:T1  result.jpg
```

or, if you are using version 6 of **ImageMagick**, use:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 320x240 gray:T1  result.jpg
```

If you want a PNG with automatic contrast-stretch, use:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 320x240 gray:T1 -auto-level result.png
```

Unfortunately none of your images come out to anything sensible. Here is T1, for example:

[image]

The histograms do look somewhat sensible though:

[image]
[image]

---

I think you have something fundamentally wrong so I would try reverting to first principles to debug it. I would shine a torch into, or point the camera at a window and save a picture called `bright.dat` and then cover the lens with a black card and take another image called `dark.dat`. Then I would plot a histogram of the data and see if the bright one was at the rightmost end and the dark one was at the leftmost end. Make a histogram like this:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 320x240 Gray:bright.dat histogram:brightHist.png
```

and:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 320x240 Gray:dark.dat histogram:darkHist.png
```

Comment: Thank you very much and yes it seems that something is fundamentally wrong with the camera code or the camera it self  so im gonna work on that but atleast with this i can see my progress and trouble shoot with ease THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,76800):
```

is a hardcoded value, and because `columnvector[0][i]` does not have that many values, you get that `IndexError: list index out of range.`

Consider why you need to set your range from 0-76800 or if the value can be dynamically sourced from `len()` of something.

Comment: im not sure what len() is but the problem with the code is that its originally made for only a row and 76800 columns while my file has 4800 row and 16 columns

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to make an image from a binary file is to convert it to a [NetPBM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) image.

As your file is 320x240 and 8-bit binary greyscale, you just need to make a header with that information in it and append your binary file:

```
printf "P5\n320 240\n255\n" >  image.pgm
cat T1                      >> image.pgm
```

You can now open `image.pgm` with `feh`, **Photoshop**, **GIMP** or many other image viewers.